# Error while inserting data into DB android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two tables in database, entries that only have column words, and another table worddictionary with columns word, definition and auduiourl,

```
 String create_table_query = "CREATE TABLE `entries` (`word` varchar(50) NOT NULL)";
 db.execSQL(create_table_query);

 String create_word_table = "CREATE TABLE `worddictionary` (`word` TEXT NOT NULL,'definition' TEXT, 'audiourl' TEXT)";
 db.execSQL(create_word_table);
```

I am trying to insert the words, its definition and audiourl that I got using web scraping into worddictionary table,

```
 String insert_query = "INSERT INTO worddictionary values("+word+","+wordDefinition+","+audioUrl+")";
 db.execSQL(insert_query);
```

But I get below error,

```
2020-07-13 14:11:56.527 27078-27131/com.example.scraping_synonyms E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "large": syntax error
2020-07-13 14:11:56.529 27078-27131/com.example.scraping_synonyms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.scraping_synonyms, PID: 27078
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "large": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO worddictionary values(aardvark,noun,
    a large, nocturnal, burrowing mammal, Orycteropus afer, of central and southern Africa, feeding on ants and termites and having a long, extensile tongue, strong claws, and long ears.
    ,https://static.sfdict.com/audio/A00/A0001900.mp3)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1770)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1698)
        at com.example.scraping_synonyms.MainActivity$Content.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.scraping_synonyms.MainActivity$Content.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:74)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

In this error, it is mentioned error near "large", that is the word in the definition
I don't understand what the error is about

Comment: asyntask error, plz post your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to insert a row of 3 columns in the table `worddictionary` but what you do is trying to insert only 1 string by concatenating the strings `word`, `wordDefinition` and `audioUrl`.

The correct syntax for an `INSERT` statement is this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

and if any of the values is a string it must be **enclosed in single quotes**.

So to be syntactically correct you should enumerate all the column names after the table's name and insert each column separately:

```
String insert_query = "INSERT INTO worddictionary (word, wordDefinition, audioUrl) values ('" + 
                      word + "', '" + wordDefinition + "', '" + audioUrl + "')";
db.execSQL(insert_query);
```

But the recommended and safe way of doing this is with the method `insert()` with `ContentValues()` which takes care of quotes in these cases:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("word", word);
cv.put("definition", wordDefinition);
cv.put("audiourl", audioUrl);
int result = db.insert("worddictionary", cv);
```

You can check the variable `result` after the insertion.
If it is `-1` then an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because the marks around `word` are different than `definition`?

And the guy I replaced used Content values so for you it would be

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("word", word);
values.put("definition", definition);
values.put("audiourl", audiourl);

db.insert("worddictionary", null, values);
```